# use accesscontrol npm package in frontend (js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

How i can use npm **accesscontrol** library in frontend

the library link :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/accesscontrol

Comment: frontend as in frontend website?  You wouldn't want to have access control logic in your client code...

Comment: I mean that i want to convery npm module to single file js that browser can read it so i can access it in frontend and write my own logic